# Filtering a list by the result of a function mapped onto it. Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of objects, and I wish to filter this list by each element's result to a certain function. I thought about using a combination of the filter and map functions but I'm unsure.
Lets say I have a list [a,b,c,d] and I want to filter this list when a function f is applied to a,b,c,d they return a value n. The resulting list would look like [a,d] if f(a) = n and f(d) = n.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is just regular `filter`. You can specify application of `f` and comparison to `n` as the filter condition:

```
list = [a,b,c,d]
filteredList = filter (\x -> f x == n) list
```

Comment: or, if you're a fan of composition, you could also write this as `filter ((== n) . f)) list` (not saying this is better, or worse - but it's an option)